# Missing $ inserted Error

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to use the CRPS formula in Latex and I am very new to it. I am getting a Missing $ inserted error from the equation below. I know it's a common problem, but I haven't been able to solve it. Please help!

```
CRPS = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }
       \left [ F_{y\right}\left (y \right )-1\left ( y \geq x\big\ \right ) \right]]^{2}dy
```

Hi, this is a part of the thesis template of my university. I am not supposed to edit the preamble.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to typeset? Note that `\left<delimiter>` should match a `\right<delimiter>` without any space e.g., `\left( .... \right)`. You can start fixing the code by `F_{y}` and removing `right}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Have you surrounded the code snippet by something like `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`?

Comment: @mico Yes. I have,

Comment: Peter is right; even though you can't modify your preamble, it would be a good exercise to make a temporary copy of your document, and start a cycle remove/compile/check until you either get down to a manageable size or the problem resolves itself (at which point you should know what command caused the error).

Comment: I would also check in nearby equations, especially those inline with your text.  Depending on your editor, it may not be too apparent if you accidentally missed a `$` (or inserted an extra one), which would certainly cause this error.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \textrm{CRPS} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
       \left[F_{y}\left(y \right)-1\left(y \geq x\right) \right]^{2}\textrm{d}y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \textrm{CRPS} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
       \left[F_{y}\left(y \right)-1\left(y \geq x\right) \right]^{2}\textrm{d}y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit:

The bunch of `\left` and `\right`s are not needed as noted in the comments. Further, this will work without `amsmath`. (I add `amsmath/mathtools` instinctively `:-)`).

Adding to the above the equation:

```
\textrm{CRPS} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
       \left[F_{y}\left(y \right)-1\left(y \geq x\right) \right]^{2}\textrm{d}y
```

when copy pasted in to http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php works for me:

[image]

Hence, if it is not working for you, you may have to give some more details for trouble shooting.

Comment: So what exactly is that inequality doing there? :)

Comment: @percusse I dunno ;-). May be OP knows.

Comment: Hi, this is a part of the thesis template of my university and I inserted


\textrm{CRPS} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
       \left[F_{y}\left(y \right)-1\left(y \geq x\right) \right]^{2}\textrm{d}y

But it doesn't work. Same error.

Any suggestions? Can we do it without using amsmath. I am not supposed to edit the preamble.

Comment: I'd also get rid of virtually all `\left` and `\right` qualifiers: they don't change the sizes of the parentheses but do mess up horizontal spacing.

Comment: I was simply using http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

to copy paste the equation code. It worked for others but not for ones which have power. Please help!

Comment: @asd, without access to more information, we won't be able to help you beyond this: this code works under normal circumstances.  Some funny stuff might be happening in your preamble, and it would be worth sharing *even if* you can't change it.

Comment: @HarishKumar -- the `equation` environment normally inserts equation numbers, and i don't see any mechanism for omitting them in your examples.  ???

Comment: @percusse: the expression `1(y \geq x)` is likely an [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Comment: Thanks for continuing to help me. I am getting these errors:
1. Missing $ interested
2. Display Math should end with $$
3. Missing $ inserted \textrm{CRPS}=\int

etc etc

Comment: Please help. My masters thesis is due in 1 week and I might have to reset it in Word if I can't figure out the equations. :-(

Comment: Interesting thing happened. When I copy pasted the code, removed the begin/end equation thing and enveloped it with $ signs at the beginning and end, the equation displays finally! No errors. But now, there are no equation numbers which messes up the whole thing. Could you please help me with getting the equation numbers back? When I use begin,end equation - it gives me the errors I mentioned below.

@barbarabeeton Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @asd:You better post a MWE. What are you trying to do? Why you are copy pasting equation in that site? Instead directly use the equation in your tex file (from `\begin{equation}.....\end{equation`) and complile the tex file with pdflatex. It should give the equation number.

Comment: @asd -- try again, replacing the dollar signs with the `\begin ... \end{equation}`.  type it in carefully; don't cut and paste.  it's just possible that there was something in one of the original lines that for some reason wasn't visible.  since it now works with the dollar signs, i can't think of any reason that `equation` shouldn't work.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Oh no confusion. I meant `\begin{equation}` itself. Sorry. I understood the shorthand :-) But `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` won't work in that site. I didn't understand why the OP wants to use that site.

Comment: @HarishKumar -- okay, thanks for the explanation.  if that site doesn't accept a "core" latex command, that's a substantial flaw if it really means to be useful for more than single expressions.  (and i shan't be listing it in any recommendations for ams authors in that case.)